# Ajax call is executing in the end even when written in starting inside $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

In my code, I am trying to load a page inside a ajax call, and after page load, I want to put data inside loaded jsp accordingly.
I have tried several things.
but nothing is working:

1. I tried below code: In below code during execution, debugger goes at line 4 then it jumps to my method at line 25 and executes that, then at last it came back to ajax then executing ajax call and shows alert.

Below code is written inside `$(document).ready(function())` .

Due to this all the division and tags are empty in my loaded jsp page.
It is showing variables directly on page after execution.

```
    if(condition1){
        var var1= data //some json data;
        if(condtition == true){
            $.ajax({ //line: 4
                type : "GET",
                contentType : "application/json",
                data : "id" + Math.random(),
                url : "url", // change to full path of file on server
                success : function (data)  // line 9
                alert("ajax call"); // line 10
                console.log("calling :home.jsp");
                $('.divClass').load('url/home.jsp');
                console.log("called");  
                },
                /* complete: function (data) {
                    alert("ajax call completed"); 
                    alert("done");
                    myFunctionToProcessData(var1); 
                     }, */
                error: function(err){
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
            }
        myFunctionToProcessData(var1);  // 25   line            
    }
```

I wan to load page first then want to insert data in to page.

I have tried .done(), .complete(), .ajaxStop() and .ajaxComplete(). these are not working .
I hope i have explained my problem.

Comment: Please explain the behavior also that why code is not executing line by line and skipped ajax call. and ajax executed at last.

Comment: **ajax is asynchronous**. If you want `myFunctionToProcessData(var1);` to execute after `ajax` call, place that function within `success` or else set `ajax` option `async` to false as in `async:false`

Comment: You can get data in jsp it's not necessary to make ajax call on load.

Comment: but without ajax call jsp is not getting appended in division. and when calling function inside ajax, division becomes empty.

Comment: async:false is working Thank you.